# Lowercase letter after certain character?

Tags: python, string

I like some ways of how `string.capwords()` behaves, and some ways of how `.title()` behaves, but not one single one.

I need abbreviations capitalized, which `.title()` does, but not `string.capwords()`, and `string.capwords()` does not capitalize letters after single quotes, so I need a combination of the two. I want to use `.title(),` and then I need to lowercase the single letter after an apostrophe only if there are no spaces between.

For example, here's a user's input:

```
string="it's e.t.!"
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
>>> "It's E.T.!"
```

`.title()` would capitalize the 's', and `string.capwords()` would not capitalize the "e.t.".

Comment: Try utilize regular expression in this scenario may be more straightforward

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use regular expression substitution (See [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)):

```
>>> s = "it's e.t.!"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"\b(?<!')[a-z]", lambda m: m.group().upper(), s)
"It's E.T.!"
```

`[a-z]` will match lowercase alphabet letter. But not after `'` (`(?<!')` - negative look-behind assertion). And the letter should appear after the word boundary; so `t` will not be matched.

The second argument to `re.sub`, `lambda` will return substitution string. (upper version of the letter) and it will be used for replacement.

Comment: argh you got there first, nice one!

Comment: Thanks! Works as expected!

Comment: @TrivisionZero, I don't get it. Could you give me example string?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ".".join( [word.capitalize() for word in "it's e.t.!".split(".")] )
b = " ".join( [word.capitalize() for word in a.split(" ")] )
print(b)
```

Edited to use the capitalize function instead. Now it's starting to look like something usable :). But this solution doesn't work with other whitespace characters. For that I would go with falsetru's solution.

Comment: Try with `it's e.t.!`, not with the string already capitalized.

Comment: whoops. Let me fix that

Comment: What if `,` is appear between words?

Comment: It still works with commas or periods between words, however, it doesn't catch other whitespace characters like newlines and tabs.

Comment: `a = ".".join( [word[0].upper()+word[1:] for word in "it's e,t,!".split(".")] ); b = " ".join( [word[0].upper()+word[1:] for word in a.split(" ")] ); b`

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use regex , you can always use this simple for loop

```
s = "it's e.t.!"
capital_s = ''
pos_quote = s.index("'")
for pos, alpha in enumerate(s):
    if pos not in [pos_quote-1, pos_quote+1]:
        alpha = alpha.upper()
    capital_s += alpha
print capital_s
```

hope this helps :)